# Stucturing multi-threaded screen sharing application

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

I am working on a screen sharing application. There are 3 main tasks which take most of the time:

- Capturing screen frame (capture function)
- Encoding screen frame to video frame (encoder function)
- Sending the video frame to the server in RTMP protocol (streamer function)

---

**Problem:**

These 3 steps are repeated forever for every screen frame. When this is done in a single thread, performance takes a hit and I can barely get 30 fps.

The BYTE* pointer of the screen frame is sent to the encoder function. After encoding, the uint8_t* pointer of the encoded video frame is sent to the streamer function. **It is clear that the encoder function has shared access to both screen frame and video frame. The same pointers are overwritten every loop with the next frame data.**

Each of these tasks depend on the previous tasks output.

How would I go about designing the **multi-threaded** model for these tasks?

---

**Methods:**

1. Using a **mutex** to lock both the screen frame and video frame when it is being updated makes it almost single-threaded (because encoder function needs both pointer to screen frame and pointer to video frame, so **locking access to those pointers** means the other tasks - capturing and streaming - **cannot be done while encoding**). The performance gain will not be much.
2. Using two `queue`. First queue to copy screen frames from the capture function - the encoder will get the copies from the first queue to encode. Second queue to copy each encoded video frame from the encoder function - the streamer function will get the copies from the second queue to send to the server. I am not sure if this is a correct way to do this.

Is the second method reasonable?

Could you share any other methods that are optimal?

Comment: First rule of performance optimization - measure your performance first before attempting to code a solution.  The bottleneck might not be where you think it is.   I suspect that your encoder function is using an entire core and the capture/streaming code uses very little CPU.  So moving encoding to a dedicated thread might not help much - which is what I think you are suggesting given the reference to a mutex.   Have you done any perf tracking to prove what solution will work?  Does your encoder work synchronously or asynchronously?

Comment: Are you using a still encoder (e.g. jpg) or a stream encoder (e.g. mpeg/mp4/h264)?  I might have a suggestion if I knew this.

Comment: I am encoding in h264 using x264 as the encoder. 
I measured each of the tasks time taken independently. Capturing takes the lowest time - around 0.015 seconds. Encoding takes mostly 0.025 to 0.04 seconds and streaming takes 0.04 to 0.07 seconds. 
Since these tasks have varying time and using mutex locks when running them in separate threads won't do much, I thought of using the second method (queue). Do you think it will work out? It's like having a buffer of these frames and processing them whenever the thread is ready. @selbie

Comment: Will atomic or condition variables be helpful when running these 3 tasks in separate threads?

Comment: `Encoding takes mostly 0.025 to 0.04 seconds` Or in other words, encoding is cpu bound at ~30 frames per second with your configuration. Consider lowering your frame rate or resolution. Your second suggestion, a producer/consumer model, has some merit.  But do be prepared to drop frames if the encoder thread can't keep up with the capture thread.  Or have the encoder thread signal back to the capture thread to change its frame rate in real time.

Comment: @NewbieCoder your second approach is a known pattern: double buffering. Game programming double [buffering](https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/double-buffer.html)

Comment: @selbie I am trying to get 60 fps. Currently it does 30 fps for 720p and ~20 fps for 1080p when single-threaded. When implementing the producer consumer model, should I **allocate memory for every frame and send their reference** to the queue or **allocate once and deep copy the data to another variable and send its reference to the queue**? Copying means to copy the whole pixel data of the screen which is 1920*1080*4 bytes for 1920x1080 screen. For the other method, I will allocate only pointers. Which one will take more time -copying or allocating memory every loop?

Comment: Unless your encoder itself can be invoked across multiple threads, which I doubt, **you can't get 60fps in real time** with your configuration of machine and settings.  The encoder can only process one frame at a time, so it's inherently single threaded.  And if it can only encode at 30fps, so amount of optimizations outside of it are going to make the encoder run faster.

Comment: It's like when my wife sends me to the grocery store and I walk.  It takes about 58 minutes to walk to and from the grocery store.  When I come back, my wife writes out a new grocery list and hands it to me. Making this list takes two minutes. So I wait two minutes for the new list and then I repeat my 58 minute walk to the grocery store.  So I can only make about 24 trips to the grocery store in a given day.  My wife decides to prepare the grocery list while I'm away so I don't wait 2 minutes between trips.  Now I can make about 25 trips per day instead of 24.  Not a huge perf improvement.

Comment: Walking to the grocery store is a metaphor for encoding a single frame.  Making out the grocery list is the analog of capturing a frame.  The preparation of the grocery store list when I'm out walking is the double-buffering technique being discussed.  But as I hope you can see now, it's only a minor improvement. Short of buying me a car (faster CPU), I can't make 48 trips in one day.

Comment: Oh, I understand now @selbie Is there any way to make it faster? I am using x264 encoder. Open Broadcaster Software also uses x264 and streams to RTMP but does it at 60 fps for 4k. It is also multi-threaded.

Comment: I don't know if your encoder is the same as what OBS uses, but why don't you reference their source code?

Comment: Look at "Frame based encoding" with multiple threads on x264.  This is probably what you want, but it might be slightly harder to code and with some quality tradeoffs in captured video.  https://code.videolan.org/videolan/x264/-/blob/master/doc/threads.txt

Comment: Hey @selbie can you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62892454/x264-output-video-is-blank-when-threading-is-enabled ? I am using slice based multi-threaded encoded but even that doesn't work correctly..