# x264 output video is blank when threading is enabled

Tags: c++, multithreading, rtmp, x264, libx264

I am using libx264 compiled from source. It was configured to get both .dll and .lib by this command

`` ./configure --disable-cli --enable-shared --extra-ldflags=-Wl,--output-def=libx264.def` ``

I am using the libx264 API in my screen-sharing program with the preset - "veryfast", tune - "zerolatency", profile - "high" and also the following settings.

```
        param.i_csp = X264_CSP_BGRA;
        param.i_threads = 1;
        param.i_width = width;
        param.i_height = height;
        param.i_fps_num = fps;
        param.i_fps_den = 1;
        param.rc.i_bitrate = bitrate;
        param.rc.i_rc_method = X264_RC_ABR;
        param.rc.b_filler = true;
        param.rc.f_rf_constant = (float)0;
        param.rc.i_vbv_max_bitrate = param.rc.i_bitrate;
        param.rc.i_vbv_buffer_size = param.rc.i_bitrate;
        param.b_repeat_headers = 0;
        param.b_annexb = 1;
```

For these settings the program works fine. I specified it as single threaded by setting `param.i_threads = 1`.
If this is removed, x264 defaults to using multiple threads and sets `param.i_threads` as 1.5x of number of cores in the CPU automatically. This will give faster performance than running in single thread.

But when I remove the `param.i_threads = 1` to make it multi-threaded, the generated output is fully grey. I cannot see any output when I view the live stream with VLC or some times I can view a weird output.

I am using this bitmap image as an example (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lv4fY.jpg). Only this same image is being encoded multiple times. When it is saved into .h264 video, it is viewable clearly. But when the encoded payload is sent through rtmp, the live stream produces very bad and weird output (or sometimes no output). This is the weird output which im seeing most of the time for this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDV35.jpg

This is the full example code in which I am both streaming and writing video file of the same picture. This is using the srs librtmp library. There is no error but the stream has weird output.

In this code if you set add `param.i_threads = 1;` then only the output stream will be viewable. The problem is that it should be viewable in both single-threaded and multi-threaded encoding.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <x264.h>
#include "srs_librtmp.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "C:/Softwares/x264/libx264.lib")

using namespace std;

int check_ret(int ret);

int main()
{
    int dts = 0;

    x264_param_t param;
    x264_t* h;
    x264_nal_t* nals;
    int i_nal;
    int pts = 0;
    int i_frame_size;
    x264_picture_t picIn;
    x264_picture_t picOut;

    x264_param_default_preset(&param, "veryfast", "zerolatency");

    //x264 settings
    param.i_csp = X264_CSP_BGRA;
    param.i_width = 1920;
    param.i_height = 1080;
    param.i_fps_num = 30;
    param.i_fps_den = 1;
    param.rc.i_bitrate = 2500;
    param.rc.i_rc_method = X264_RC_ABR;
    param.rc.b_filler = true;
    param.rc.f_rf_constant = (float)0;
    param.rc.i_vbv_max_bitrate = param.rc.i_bitrate;
    param.rc.i_vbv_buffer_size = param.rc.i_bitrate;
    param.b_repeat_headers = 0;
    param.b_annexb = 1;

    x264_param_apply_profile(&param, "high");
    h = x264_encoder_open(&param);

    //allocate picture
    x264_picture_alloc(&picIn, param.i_csp, param.i_width, param.i_height);

    //picture settings
    picIn.img.i_plane = 1;
    picIn.img.i_stride[0] = 4 * param.i_width;
    picIn.i_type = X264_TYPE_AUTO;

    int header_size = x264_encoder_headers(h, &nals, &i_nal);
    FILE* fptr;
    fopen_s(&fptr, "example1.h264", "wb");
    // write sps and pps in the video file
    fwrite(nals->p_payload, header_size, 1, fptr);

    int size = 1920 * 1080 * 4;
    char* bmp = new char[size];
    FILE* bitptr;
    errno_t err = fopen_s(&bitptr, "flower.bmp", "rb");
    fseek(bitptr, 54, SEEK_SET);
    fread(bmp, size, 1, bitptr);
    fclose(bitptr);

    srs_rtmp_t rtmp = srs_rtmp_create("127.0.0.1:1935/live/test");

    if (srs_rtmp_handshake(rtmp) != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Simple handshake failed.";
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "Handshake completed successfully.\n";

    if (srs_rtmp_connect_app(rtmp) != 0) {
        std::cout << "Connecting to host failed.";
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "Connected to host successfully.\n";

    if (srs_rtmp_publish_stream(rtmp) != 0) {
        std::cout << "Publish signal failed.";
    }

    std::cout << "Publish signal success\n";

    // write sps and pps in the live stream
    int ret = srs_h264_write_raw_frames(rtmp, reinterpret_cast<char*>(nals->p_payload), header_size, 0, 0);
    ret = check_ret(ret);
    if (!ret)
        return -1;
    std::cout << "SPS and PPS sent.\n";

    // main loop
    std::cout << "Now streaming and encoding\n";
    int i = 1800;
    while (i--)
    {

        picIn.img.plane[0] = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(bmp);
        picIn.i_pts = pts++;
        i_frame_size = x264_encoder_encode(h, &nals, &i_nal, &picIn, &picOut);
        if (i_frame_size)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < i_nal; j++)
            {

                x264_nal_t* nal = nals + j;
                // write data in the video file
                fwrite(nal->p_payload, nal->i_payload, 1, fptr);
                // write data in the live stream
                ret = srs_h264_write_raw_frames(rtmp, reinterpret_cast<char*>(nal->p_payload), nal->i_payload, dts, dts);
                ret = check_ret(ret);
                if (!ret)
                {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "i_frame_size = 0 (encoder failed)\n";
        }
        dts += 33;
    }

    while (x264_encoder_delayed_frames(h))
    {
        i_frame_size = x264_encoder_encode(h, &nals, &i_nal, NULL, &picOut);
        if (i_frame_size)
        {
            fwrite(nals->p_payload, i_frame_size, 1, fptr);
        }
    }

    std::cout << "\nAll done\n";
    std::cout << "Output video is example1.h264 and it is viewable in VLC";

    return 0;
}

int check_ret(int ret)
{
    if (ret != 0) {
        if (srs_h264_is_dvbsp_error(ret)) {
            srs_human_trace("ignoring drop video error, code=%d", ret);
        }
        else if (srs_h264_is_duplicated_sps_error(ret)) {
            srs_human_trace("ignoring duplicated sps, code=%d", ret);
        }
        else if (srs_h264_is_duplicated_pps_error(ret)) {
            srs_human_trace("ignoring duplicated pps, code=%d", ret);
        }
        else {
            srs_human_trace("sending h264 raw data failed. ret=%d", ret);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

If you would like to download the original flower.bmp file, here is the link: https://gofile.io/d/w2kX56
This error can be reproduced in any other bmp file also.

Please tell me what is causing this problem when multi-threading is enabled. Am I setting wrong values? Is the code in which I am streaming the encoded data wrong?

Comment: Please post a minimal functional example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Ok I will post the code soon. It works when I save the data as .h264 video.. But it fails on streaming.

Comment: @szatmary can you please check it now? I have added full example code, bitmap image which can be used for testing and also the weird live stream output image.

Comment: @szatmary I would love your guidance for this new question, please check it 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63548229/playback-of-x264-encoded-video-in-flv-is-very-slow-screen-recording